# How to change the language of the app when THE USER selects the language?

Tags: android, multilingual, idioms, multiple-languages

How to change the language of the app when THE USER selects the language?

I want to do almost this: http://snowpard-android.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/programmatically-change-language-in.html?google_comment_id=z13isbsazkf3hzea504celo5oy3rjzbyevo0k

but instead of changing the language of a textView, I want to create a button with the name of the language, and when the user clicks on it, it goes to a second page already translated. I already created new values with the languages, but can't think about a code that could open another page with those strings. Could anyone help me, plssss?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android

Comment: You can learn from [Android-LocalizationActivity](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-LocalizationActivity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to pass the language name as an intent extra in the first activity and get it in the second activity and update the language accordingly. Consider the following

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // findViewbyId here for button
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("lang", "fr");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and in the other activity

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    private void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String lang = getIntent().getStringExtra("lang") == null ? getIntent().getStringExtra("lang") : "en";

        // assuming this is the method you have to call to change the language
        changeLang(en);
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use localization for achieving this on on click .

```
       String languageToLoad  = "hi"; // change your language her this is for hindi
  Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
  Configuration config = new Configuration();
   config.locale = locale;
  getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
  getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
 this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: I don't want to use location because the user must select the language of the app

Comment: So exactly what you want

Comment: I want to give the user the option to choose the language of the app with no need to change the language of his cellphone. If I use location, the app will translate automatically (that's not what I want).My idea was creating 4 buttons (corresponding to the 4 languages) and when the user clicks on them, it goes to a second page already translated.